# Not able to get data by subQueries (multiple subQueries with no direct relation)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

i want to get data from user_login table which contains following fields:

user_login : id,  status,  date, user_id

in this table status can be 1 or 2

if status is 1 then login else logout.

i want to get login and logout both details in one row for this i tried this query:

```
select login.date, logout.date from 
(select date from user_login where userId = 1 and status = 1 and date = now()) login, 
(select date from user_login where userId = 1 and status = 2 and date = now()) logout.
```

i get data when both login and logout has data. but i also want when only login has data but not logout.

Please help me in solving this prob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN`. Like this:

```
select login.date, logout.date 
from 
    (
        select 
            userId,
            date 
        from 
            user_login where userId = 1 and status = 1 and date = now()
    ) 
        login
LEFT JOIN
    (
        select 
            date,
            userId 
        from 
            user_login 
        where
            status = 2 
            and date = now()
    ) logout
        ON logout.userId=login.userId
```

Or I think that the better solution would be to do something like this:

```
SELECT
    user_login.userId,
    MAX(CASE WHEN user_login.status=1 THEN date ELSE NULL END) AS loginDate,
    MAX(CASE WHEN user_login.status=2 THEN date ELSE NULL END) AS logoutDate,
FROM
    user_login
WHERE
    user_login.userId=1
    AND date = now()
GROUP BY
    user_login.userId
```

Comment: i tried this before but not get data because i am not using MAX(). can you tell me why we need to use MAX(). AND YES THANK ur both query works fine and second is better

Comment: Because you will have to rows one for status=1 and one for status=2. If you use max then you will just select the row which have both max of status 1 and status 2.